# Catching exceptions in IronPython WPF script

Tags: ironpython

I'm working on a tool that allows users to extend it by creating and executing Python scripts inside the tool. The Python scripts gets executed by IronPython and these scripts can have WPF based user interfaces. The problem is that when an exception is thrown inside IronPython, for example as a result of a snippet of code getting executed when a button is pressed, the entire tool crashes because the exception propagates all the way back to the start of the application without being caught. Is there a way to equip IronPython, or the Microsoft script engine, with an error handler that gets called when an exception is thrown?

Here is a piece of callstack when an exception is thrown.

```
StackTrace:
at IronPython.Runtime.Operations.PythonOps.GetVariable(CodeContext context, String name, Boolean isGlobal, Boolean lightThrow)
at IronPython.Compiler.LookupGlobalInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run4[T0,T1,T2,T3,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object , RoutedEventArgs )
at _Scripting_(Object[] , Object , RoutedEventArgs )
at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
```

Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried... catching the exceptions?